# Prove that if $P(n) = P(m)$ for positive integers $m$ and $n$, then $n = m$

Tags: number-theory

> Let the product of the positive divisors of a positive integer $n$ be denoted by $P(n)$. Prove that if $P(n) = P(m)$ for positive integers $m$ and $n$, then $n = m$.

We know that the product of the positive divisors of an integer $n$ is $n^{d(n)/2}$ where $d(n)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $n$. Thus, $n^{d(n)/2} = m^{d(m)/2}$ and so $n^{d(n)} = m^{d(m)}$. Then both $n$ and $m$ must have the same prime divisors and so we can let $$n = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_n^{\alpha_n} \quad \text{and} \quad m = p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2} \cdots p_n^{\beta_n}.$$ Note that $d(n) = (\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1) \cdots (\alpha_n+1)$ and $d(m) = (\beta_1+1)(\beta_2+1) \cdots (\beta_n+1)$ and so we need $$\alpha_i(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1) \cdots (\alpha_n+1) = \beta_i(\beta_1+1)(\beta_2+1) \cdots (\beta_n+1)$$ for each $i$. How can I continue?

Comment: To continue from where you left off, write $n$ as a product of prime powers $q = p^r$, and consider the exponent of $p$ in $n^{d(n)}$ and $m^{d(m)}$.

Comment: Perhaps the contrapositive statement $ n \not= m \implies P(n) \not = P(m)$ may be easier to prove.

Comment: $\beta_i/\alpha_i=c$

Answer (score 2):

Let $c = d(m)/d(n)$. Then for all primes $p_i$ we have $e_{p_i}(n) = ce_{p_i}(m)$ where $e_{p_i}(n)$ denotes the exponent of $p_i$ in the prime factorization of $n$. If $c < 1$, then we would have $e_{p_i}(n) < e_{p_i}(m)$, which would imply that $n < m$ and $d(m) < d(n)$ and thus $P(n) < P(m)$, a contradiction. Similarly if $c > 1$ then we would have $P(n) > P(m)$. Thus we must have $c = 1$ and so $n = m$.