# Prove that the product of all the positive divisors of two numbers is equal implies the numbers themselves are equal.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, divisor-counting-function

Let $P(n)$ and $P(m)$ be the product of all the positive divisors of $n$ and $m$, two positive integers.

I know that $P(n) = n^{T(n)/2}$ and $P(m) = m^{T(m)/2}$, where $T(n)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $n$. But then proving that $n = m$ from this is just as difficult as the original problem.. If I write $n$ and $m$ in their prime factored forms, I can conclude that for each $i$, we must have $T(n) k_i = T(m) s_i$, where $k_i$ and $s_i$ are the exponents of $p_i$ and $q_i$ in the prime factored forms of $n$ and $m$. But again, I have to prove that $T(n) = T(m)$.
Could someone give me a proof for why the product being equal implies the number of divisors is equal?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken combinatorics?

Comment: Other than highschool, no.

Comment: Same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184121/prove-that-if-pn-pm-for-positive-integers-m-and-n-then-n-m?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the symmetry we can assume $n \ge m$.  To look for a contradiction, assume $n \gt m$.  We then have $n=m^{\frac {T(m)}{T(n)}}$ which says ${\frac {T(m)}{T(n)}} \gt 1.$ Let $\operatorname{ord}_p(n)$ denote the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$. If you look at each prime that divides $m$ the same relationship exists:
$\operatorname{ord}_p(n)={\frac {T(m)}{T(n)}}\operatorname{ord}_p(m)$.  But $T(m)$ is the product of $(\operatorname{ord}_p+1)$ over all the primes dividing $m$.  Since the orders are greater for $n$, we have $T(n) \gt T(m)$, a contradiction.  We conclude $n=m$.

Comment: What does the notation $ord_p$ mean?

Comment: The exponent of a prime dividing a number.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense.