# Range of the map "product of positive divisors"

Tags: number-theory

For all positive integer $n$, let $P(n)$ be the product of all (positive) divisors of $n$.

It is well known that $P(n)=n^{d(n)/2}$ where $d(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$.

It is also known that $P$ is an injective map (see for example [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528727/prove-that-the-product-of-all-the-positive-divisors-of-two-numbers-is-equal-impl)).

Now my question : what is the range of $P$ ? In other words, what are the positive integers $q$ which can be written $P(n)$ for some $n$ ?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528727/prove-that-the-product-of-all-the-positive-divisors-of-two-numbers-is-equal-impl?rq=1) is the link.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okay, I edit my post to insert that link, thank you

Comment: Didn't you just describe the range of $P$? You have your formula.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: No, I am expecting some characterization of those integers that are attained by $P$.

Comment: I think this is the list for the range: http://oeis.org/A174895

Comment: @SteveKass: Yes, I discovered it meanwhile, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $n = \prod_{i=1}^k\, p_i^{e_i}$, where the $p_i>1$ are distinct primes and the $e_i\geq 1$ are their exponents, then

\begin{align}
P(n)
&=
{\left(\prod_{i=1}^k\, p_i^{e_i}\right)}^{^{\left(\displaystyle\frac12\,\prod_{i=1}^k\,(1+e_i)\right)}}.
\end{align}

Hence, the range of $P$ is

$$
\left\{m \in \mathbb N\,\middle|\,
(\exists k\geq 1)\, (\exists \, \text{ exponents }\, e_1,e_2, \dots, e_k\geq 1\, \text{ and distinct primes }\, p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k)\,\\
m =  {\left(\prod_{i=1}^k\, p_i^{e_i}\right)}^{\left(\displaystyle\frac12\,\prod_{i=1}^k\,(1+e_i)\right)}
\right\}.$$

In other words, for each choice of integer $k\geq 1$, integer exponents $e_1,\dots,e_k\geq 1$ and distinct primes $p_1,\dots,p_k>0$ there is a corresponding $m$ in the range of $P$, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't add any useful information, since I already know that explicit formula for $P(n)$. What I was expecting is a characterization like : the range of $P$ is the set of positive integers whose number of primes divisors doesn't exceed $\log_2(n)/7$ or whatever...

Comment: This seems like a rather vague description. I'm stil not quite sure what you're looking for

Comment: Okay, let me try to be more specific. Consider for example the map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2,(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,xy)$.
It's correct to say that its range is the set of all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\exists (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x+y=a$ and $xy=b$. But this is merely the definition of the range of that map. A better description is as follows : its range is the set of all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $a^2-4b\geq 0$.